# How to add images in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table

I want to add photos in my attribute table. I have created a new field but I am not able to select "raster" in the field type. They only show "short integer", "long integer", "float", "double", "text" and "date".

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software, version and license level that you are using, please?  In this case, if you are using ArcGIS for Desktop, the latter two details will be important to know.  Also, include where you are storing this data e.g. file geodatabase feature class, shapefile, etc.

Comment: Arcmap v.10.2 Free trial.

Comment: I store the data in my C:\student. I am using a laptop now.

Comment: You can, of course, MIME encode the image and store it as a text field, but I'm guessing that's not the answer you seek?

Comment: A shapefile cannot contain an attribute field to hold raster datasets but if you are using a geodatabase it is doable.

Comment: You could also use hyperlinks to reference the images.http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000004000000

Comment: Hi Barrycarter, I try to store it as a text field, however I won't be able to "load" images in the attribute table.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to associate a photo with a vector data set, such as a point or polygon, which could be accessed through a pop-up window. Although a photograph is indeed a raster, it sounds like you may be confusing raster data type with linking to a photograph. In ArcGIS the latter can be achieved in a couple ways:

(1) If you are using a shape or feature you could achieve this by using a hyperlink to link to your photo, either on your local drive or somewhere public on the web. ESRI has good [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000004000000) on this.

(2) If you are working in a geodatabase you could attach the photo, using the [Add Attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000014v000000) tool.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AWFvU6no_Q   Indeed, I followed this link " how to insert image in attribute table. This is what I want.

Comment: I've successfully attached the photos. Thank you again for the link you provided. I also found another one. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m900000002000000

Answer (score 0):

You can add the field "raster" to the atributte table just if you are working with geodatabase. I find this tutorial that I think is what you were looking for:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AWFvU6no_Q

Answer (score -1):

it here for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62LlVqOo8RM
You can insert an image to feature's attribute and show it in ArcMap

Comment: You aren't inserting an image to feature's attribute table, hyperlink isn't the same.